# `[~,ui] = Unique(Day)` what is this doing?

Tags: matlab

When looking at Matlab code I have stumbled upon the following line of code:

`[~,ui] = Unique(Day)`

(Where Day is the vector containing a numeric value of day like so: 1,2,3, etc.)

What is it doing? I have noticed that it creates some kind of unique identifiers for the numeric value of the day (i.e. for 1 to 31) as well as a variable called Volume. What is Volume?

Comment: http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[~,ui] = Unique(Day)` evaluates the function `Unique` with input argument `Day`.

This function has 2 outputs, and if you want to use both, you would write
`[a,b]=Unique(Day)`. However, if you need only second output, you can put `~` instead of the first argument. So, your first output will not be saved.

It is impossible to answer, what `Volume` means, because you didn't provide the code of the function `Unique`.

Comment: Alright. Actually, I think Volume is there from the start. I did not know that ~ functions like that. Got it. Thanks

Comment: in my case it returns the index values of the original matrix (day) of the unique values.

Comment: Again, it is impossible to determine what it returns without looking at the code of you function.

Comment: It is not my function, it is the usual matlab unique function